# How to take out scroll bars in <object> tag (or other substitution) across all browsers?

Tags: html, cross-browser

I'm trying to take the scroll bars out of an `<object>` tag in HTML.

```
<object id="page" type="text/html" data="http://cmsmichael.prowonline.com/charts/MBA_UNC/775/2.2.2/Parabula01.php" width="420" height="315" style="overflow:hidden; width: 420px; height: 315px">
<a href="http://cmsmichael.prowonline.com/charts/MBA_UNC/775/2.2.2/Parabula01.php" target="_blank">Chart not showing? Click Here.</a>
</object>
```

Originally I was trying to use an `<iframe>` tag but after reading around on the web it seemed like an `<object>` tag would be a better way to go. Basically what I need to do is show a border-less web page which has a Google chart in it and I need it to work across all browsers. So far the above code works in Firefox but in Chrome the borders show up again. Haven't tested in IE yet.

Should I use a different HTML tag or is there something I should do differently with this object tag to achieve this?

Your input is greatly appreciated, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because, "The object support in browsers depend on the object type. Unfortunately, the major browsers use different codes to load the same object type." (http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_object.asp)

so, when you check the html source from Chrome developer tools you can see object tag in rendered html. and when you check the html source from firebug you can see iframe tag with scrolling="no" property in rendered html instead of object tag.

you can use following line for cross browser if you prefer :

```
<iframe src="http://cmsmichael.prowonline.com/charts/MBA_UNC/775/2.2.2/Parabula01.php"  width="420" height="315" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with object tag browsed by IE. My object tag contained a jpg image and the image always had scroll bars if browsed by IE, but it was OK if browsed by Chrome or Firefox. But my file was a PHP file and I discovered that if I placed PHP tag before HTML tag, the source code would have some invisible codes before the HTML tag. I then tried placing the HTML tag (also HEAD tag) before any PHP tag and the problem was solved. Therefore, if your file is a PHP file, do not place PHP tag before HTML tag if it is not necessary. Internet Explorer may not remove these invisible codes from the source code, and then, create scrollbars around object tag. However, if your PHP file contains session, placing HTML tag before PHP tag may causes error.